# Docker のレイヤー数の制限はどこから取得できる？

Tags: docker

Docker には、作成できるレイヤー数に制限があると聞きました。

この上限数は、`docker` プログラム自体から取得できるものなのでしょうか。
それとも、公式ドキュメントのどこかしらに記載があるのでしょうか。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
MAX_N=500

docker pull ubuntu
docker tag ubuntu test_ubuntu_img

for ((i=0;i<${MAX_N};i++)); do
    docker run --name=test_ubuntu test_ubuntu_img /bin/bash -c \
            "echo $i > ${i}.txt"
    docker commit test_ubuntu test_ubuntu_img
    docker rm -v test_ubuntu
done

docker rmi test_ubuntu_img
```

上記のようなスクリプトを実行して、実証的に layer 数を判定することはできました。
(上限である 128 layer に達するとエラーメッセージを出力するようになる)